# Android gradients with banding artifact

Tags: android, image, bitmap, gradient, artifact

I am having a problem with Android graphics. I am doing game development and need to display images some of which have color gradients. My problem is that when I load bitmap images (in png format) with gradients the images display with a banding artifact. And this is on Android 4. I researched numerous posts relating to this issue, and tried numerous solutions including:

1. Dithering the image on input

   ```
   BitmapFactory.Options factoryOptions = 
     new BitmapFactory.Options();
   factoryOptions.inDither = true;
   ...
   background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( resources, R.drawable.game_page_background, factoryOptions );
   ```
2. Loading the image from "res/raw" instead of "res/drawable"
3. Verifying the pixel format of my display as: Bitmap Config ARGB_8888
4. Loading the image from the assets directory using an input stream.

I assumed Solutions 2 and 4 should have prevented Android image "optimization" which (again I assume) is producing the artifact. But none of the solutions work. The artifact remains no matter how I load the bitmap. In the end I had to do a horrible workaround which was to bake noise into the image using photoshop. Obviously, this is a horrible workaround.

Can anyone from this community offer any further advice as to how to get bitmap images with gradients to render smoothly in Android without the banding artifact?

The following code frags show how I've generated these test images...

CODE FRAG **

```
...
InputStream is = null;
try
{
    is = ((Activity)gameMngr).getAssets().open("test_background_3.png");
}
catch( IOException ioe)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST CODE: Unable to open resources. ");
}
this.background = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
...

// ELSEWHERE
...
canvas.drawBitmap( this.background, 0, 0, null );
...
```

END FRAG **

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a copy of your from decodeStream and specify the Bitmap COnfig
Here is the revised code frag of yours:

```
InputStream is = null;
try
{
    is = ((Activity)gameMngr).getAssets().open("test_background_3.png");
}
catch( IOException ioe)
{
    Log.d(TAG, "TEST CODE: Unable to open resources. ");
}
this.background = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

//create copy and specify the config of the bitmap, setting to true make the bitmap
//mutable.
Bitmap newBtmp = this.background.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

//use the newBtmp object
canvas.drawBitmap( newBtmp, 0, 0, null );
...
```

If this post helps you, please make this post as an answer.

Thanks.